# How do I give permission to specific roles using claims and policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, permissions

I have a Role manager set up in my ASP.NET Core 6 project where each role can be granted certain access to the application. I have claims and policy to authorize such access. Unfortunately the problem is: I am always getting the "Access denied" page even though the user is authenticated and have the correct role and permissions as well as claims.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TheGospelMission.Constants
{
    public static class Permissions
    {
        public static List<string> GeneratePermissionsForModule(string module)
        {
            return new List<string>()
            {
                $"Permission.{module}.All",
                $"Permission.{module}.Create",
                $"Permission.{module}.View",
                $"Permission.{module}.Edit",
                $"Permission.{module}.Delete",
            };
        }

        public static class Admin
        {
            public const string All = "Permission.Admin.All";
            public const string View = "Permission.Admin.View";
            public const string Create = "Permission.Admin.Create";
            public const string Edit = "Permission.Admin.Edit";
            public const string Delete = "Permission.Admin.Delete";
        }

        public static class Roles
        {
            public const string All = "Permission.Admin.All";
        }

        public static class Church
        {
            public const string View = "Permission.Church.View";
            public const string Create = "Permission.Church.Create";
            public const string Edit = "Permission.Church.Edit";
            public const string Delete = "Permission.Church.Delete";
        }

        public static class Members
        {
            public const string View = "Permission.Members.View";
            public const string Create = "Permission.Members.Create";
            public const string Edit = "Permission.Members.Edit";
            public const string Delete = "Permission.Members.Delete";
        }

        public static class Groups
        {
            public const string View = "Permission.Groups.View";
            public const string Create = "Permission.Groups.Create";
            public const string Edit = "Permission.Groups.Edit";
            public const string Delete = "Permission.Groups.Delete";
        }

        public static class Attendances
        {
            public const string View = "Permission.Attendances.View";
            public const string Create = "Permission.Attendances.Create";
            public const string Edit = "Permission.Attendances.Edit";
            public const string Delete = "Permission.Attendances.Delete";
        }
    }
}
```

`ClaimsHelper` class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using TheGospelMission.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TheGospelMission.Helpers
{
    public static class ClaimsHelper
    {
        public static void GetPermissions(this List<RoleClaimsViewModel> allPermissions, Type policy, string roleId)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = policy.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
            {
                allPermissions.Add(new RoleClaimsViewModel { Value = fi.GetValue(null).ToString(), Type = "Permissions" });
            }
        }

        public static async Task AddPermissionClaim(this RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IdentityRole role, string permission)
        {
            var allClaims = await roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);

            if (!allClaims.Any(a => a.Type == "Permission" && a.Value == permission))
            {
                await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim("Permission", permission));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Permission folder:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TheGospelMission.Permission
{
    internal class PermissionAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PermissionAuthorizationHandler> _logger;

        public PermissionAuthorizationHandler(ILogger<PermissionAuthorizationHandler> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
        {
            try
            {
                if (context.User == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("User Claims:");

                foreach (var claim in context.User.Claims)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"{claim.Type}: {claim.Value}");
                }

                var permissions = context.User.Claims.Where(x =>
                    x.Type == "Permissions" &&
                    x.Value == requirement.Permission &&
                    x.Issuer == "LOCAL AUTHORITY");

                if (permissions.Any())
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error during permission authorization");
            }

            context.Fail(); // Authorization failed
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TheGospelMission.Permission
{
    internal class PermissionPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PermissionPolicyProvider> _logger;

        public DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider FallbackPolicyProvider { get; }

        public PermissionPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options, ILogger<PermissionPolicyProvider> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            // There can only be one policy provider in ASP.NET Core.
            // We only handle permissions related policies, for the rest
            /// we will use the default provider.
            FallbackPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
        }

        public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync() => FallbackPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();

        // Dynamically creates a policy with a requirement that contains the permission.
        // The policy name must match the permission that is needed.

        public Task<AuthorizationPolicy?> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
        {
            if (policyName.StartsWith("Permission", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
                policy.AddRequirements(new PermissionRequirement(policyName));
                var createdPolicy = policy.Build();

                // Log information about the created policy
                _logger.LogInformation($"Created policy '{policyName}': {string.Join(", ", createdPolicy.Requirements.Select(r => r.GetType().Name))}");
                return Task.FromResult<AuthorizationPolicy?>(policy.Build());
            }

            // Policy is not for permissions, try the default provider.
            return FallbackPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
        }

        public Task<AuthorizationPolicy?> GetFallbackPolicyAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthorizationPolicy?>(null);
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace TheGospelMission.Permission
{
    internal class PermissionRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public string Permission { get; private set; }

        public PermissionRequirement(string permission)
        {
            Permission = permission;
        }
    }
}
```

Log info

```
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          User Claims:
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: User Claims:
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: d66790ae-e8ea-4e09-a142-ea76def0199e
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: d66790ae-e8ea-4e09-a142-ea76def0199e
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: TestUser
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: TestUser
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: tt@mail.com
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: tt@mail.com
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp: P2KUBBQ6NCGLXTQKBDDQVRUQ3QVQS6WW
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp: P2KUBBQ6NCGLXTQKBDDQVRUQ3QVQS6WW
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          Permission: Permission.Members.View
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: Permission: Permission.Members.View
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          Permission: Permission.Members.Create
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: Permission: Permission.Members.Create
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          Permission: Permission.Members.View
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: Permission: Permission.Members.View
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Group Leader
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Group Leader
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: Permission: Permission.Members.Create
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          Permission: Permission.Members.Create
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          Permission: Permission.Members.View
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: Permission: Permission.Members.View
    info: TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler[0]
          amr: pwd
    TheGospelMission.Permission.PermissionAuthorizationHandler: Information: amr: pwd
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that with me I hope my changes made it fit properly according to guideline.

Comment: A policy can `.RequireRole` or `.RequireClaim` easily enough, I'm not sure why you'd bother to create your own requirement handler. And I have no idea why you've written your `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider` service, instead of just configuring `AuthorizationOptions`.

Comment: well I was following a tutorial to try and learn and understand how this all works and the tutorial did it this way but please do enlighten me with a better way if you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for here. Are you simply trying to authorize users for specific actions? If so, there's built in ways to do that with asp.net core Identity classes.

I'd scrap everything you posted and go back to basics, unless you haven't given us all the context here.

Create a controller, which I believe you already have. Decorate it with the Authorize attribute and specify the role(s) allowed to access it. You can do this at the method level too.

Then just create a DbContaxt class that implements IdentityDbContext.

That's the very basics. And it's really all that's needed to authenticate users with role access.

As an example,

Create a DbContext class:

```
public class UserIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>
    {
        public UserIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

Ensure a connection string exists in your appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "UserIdentity": "Server=.;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  }
```

Ensure the DB is setup using package manager console:

```
Add-Migration Setup
Update-Database
```

Have a controller for logging in of course:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthenticateController(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

            var token = GetToken(authClaims);

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

And then just use the Authorize attribute where users should have access based roles:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
public class AdminController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "whatever you want";
    }
}
```

I assume you already setup some type of auth in the program.cs file but if not, then :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

// Adding Jwt Bearer
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
        ValidIssuer = configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
    };
});
```

That's all you'd need. You don't need to implement everything yourself.

Comment: My purpose of not having it just by roles is because there will be a case where there will be users who  will have the same role but require  different permission/access.

Comment: And why can't you just give them multiple roles? Like Editor, Creator, Deleter? Or in your case, Admin, Super Admin, ChurchReadOnly, etc. A user can be assigned many roles so I don't see your need to reinvent everything.

Comment: but giving them multiple roles wouldnt that just get complicated as well. long turn. what if I need two different types of admins.  which then mean when i'm placing the authorize attribute over routes I will have such a long list of roles

Comment: Well if you plan to allow many roles to access a route and not keep things simple, I'd suggest going the way my old workplace handled that exact situation.

You can have a mapping in the database for roles to routes. Aka, for every route in your app, have a mapping entry in the DB to what roles can access it.

Then in the backend have your own attribute OR base controller, that checks the users roles against the allowed roles for the route they are trying access. Would be easier than trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: do you have an example or is that the example you provided in the answer.

Comment: i created a branch https://github.com/Timmysworld/TheGospelMission2/tree/JWT/TheGospelMission i am trying to implement what you suggested in the answer. I created a Authentication service to handle the logic for the login page base on login.cshtml.cs but i am running into an issue where i cant get to the login form now.